# Mysql Delete Query from tow table

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

Hello I Have write Delete Query

```
delete installments . InstallmentID , Installment_part . InstallmentID  , Installment_part.Parts_ID ,Installment_part.*  FROM installments
    INNER JOIN
Installment_part ON installments.InstallmentID = Installment_part.InstallmentID 
WHERE
(((installments.InstallmentID) = 7)
AND ((Installment_part.InstallmentID) = 7));
```

It Give me this Error Unknown Table InstallmentID 
i have change it to Select Statement and it show me what i want to Delete

Comment: Please refer to MySQL documentation on how to structure DELETE FROM statements http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: thanks for your help i will give it try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE im.*,imp.* FROM installments im
    INNER JOIN
Installment_part imp ON im.InstallmentID = imp.InstallmentID 
WHERE im.InstallmentID = 7;
```

Comment: Try this and let me know

Comment: it  work fine in the select statement but it give me 1175 mysql error for the delete its says that i have to use primary key as i see that im.InstallmentID  is the primary key